# BQ snapshot - set timestamp from the past

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a snapshot of a table using SQL. I want to capture the data as of 8am UTC today. Wrote the following code but it returns errors, probably the issue is in the last line but I can't figure out what the syntax should be. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE SNAPSHOT TABLE `project.dataset.table_snapshot`
CLONE `project.dataset.table`
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp = TIMESTAMP "2023-03-10 00:08:00 UTC",
  timestamp = "2023-02-10 00:08:00 UTC"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp is in the future, it is in March.

Timetravel is supported in `SELECT` statements only.

```sql
#CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table_snapshot`
# OPTIONS( expiration_timestamp = TIMESTAMP "2023-03-10 00:08:00 UTC" )
SELECT *
FROM `mydataset.mytable`
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF "2023-02-10 00:08:00 UTC"
```

Comment: it's the snapshot expiration that was set for the future. The code you shared works great, thank you. How would I go about specifying an expiration (March 10th) right away?